# Wordpress template page for custom posts

Tags: wordpress, templates, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type (that I'm using on a template page), the custom post type is called 'Headerhome'.
When I post say a gallery there I'm trying to get it to redirect to 'single-Headerhome.php', yet it always just goes to 'single.php'.

The name of the custom post type itself is arbitrary, the name of the templage page it's on is 'home'.

I'm really confused, I'm not the best at WP yet so when something simple like this doesn't work I have no idea how to fix it, even after pouring over the codex for an hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The name of the custom post type itself is arbitrary, the name of the templage page it's on is 'home'.

Reading this implies that you have a home.php file in your theme, which would automatically display as your front page of your site. This may not be what you desire?  More on this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page

An example of a custom post type might be an Event. The Event might have custom fields associated with it, like Location, Date, Time, Description. We would probably want new Events to show up on our front page, but also would want to create a custom theme file so when a user clicks on an Event from the home page to view the Event then the Event page shows our Date, Time, Location, Description, etc. We would then create a single-event.php to do this and put in any custom code their.

So (another example), a custom post type of Fruit would have an associated theme file of single-fruit.php. If their is no single-fruit.php then Wordpress will use single.php as the default theme file to display. More on this here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types#Template_Files

Hope this helps set you in the right direction.

Comment: Typically you can use the single.php template file as a starting point for a new custom post type. Copy single.php and rename it to single-{yourposttype}.php, add any custom code, remove anything you don't want, and go from there.

Comment: My page is set up to use 'homepage.php', the title of the page is portfolio.
The custom post type is 'Headerhome', what you just described is exactly what I want, but no amount of renaming of files gets it to use anything but single.php.
I create a page called single-Headerhome.php and it doesnt redirect to it.

Comment: I should probably add :-
Home page is a 'static template' called homepage.php.
Post type is ON the static page called 'Headerhome'.
I'd like gallery images etc to redirect to something other than single.php.